# Handeling Videos in AIR IOS actionscript 3

Tags: ios, actionscript-3

Currently what I am doing is exporting my videos as .FLV files... Dragging them into flash cs6 and using the embedding options (it just pops up when I drag it into flash) to store them as a movie clip in my library.
now when I debug it each time I ask for the video clip to show up (addChild) it bumps up my memory usage(I am using task manager to monitor it) which is fine but when it remove it from the stage including all it's event handlers the memory it uses doesn't drop back down,and more time it gets added onto the stage more memory increase it create.

So the questions are:

- Is there any specific way i have to handle videos in flash? it doesn't seem to remove the instances properly...
- What is the best way of importing and using videos in flash cs6 for AIR IOS?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend, OSMF. OSMF is a great tool. For video playback. is supported H264, mp4 and flv.

In Air for iOS is many used for streaming service. More Information, search a Adobe forum.

> Open Source Media Framework (OSMF) simplifies the development of media
>   players by allowing developers to assemble components to create
>   high-quality, full-featured video playback experiences. This open
>   framework enables development focused on web-based video monetization,
>   with lower costs and faster turnaround.

OSMF Site: [OSMF](http://www.opensourcemediaframework.com/)

OSMF Adobe Forum: [OSMF Adobe Forum](http://forums.adobe.com/community/opensource/osmf)

OSMF Documentation: [OSMF Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/org/osmf/media/package-detail.html)

OSMF Sample Code: [OSMF Market Place](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/marketplace/index.cfm?event=marketplace.home&marketplaceid=3)